# Ruby on rails form generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails

In this tutorial. Can anyone tell me how is the `form` getting generated.

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

1. Where is the :article hash coming from?.
2. `f.label` corresponds to the form object, where is the `:title` coming from?.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this guide can answer your question:

[RailsGuides - Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Take a look the "[2 Dealing with Model Objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)" session

Answer (score 1):

1. You are calling form_for with the symbol `:article` which means that the form creates a new instance of Article for use in the form.
2. I've not tested this code but I would imagine `:title` is an attribute of Article, either a field in the database or a virtual attribute ect.

Comment: It does work with the symbol :article or any other too. Is it just a common name used there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you would just keep following along the tutorial in [section 5.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-article-model) the root for this elements is explained.